# Radio Button On Click Submit Input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, radio-button

How can i make when i chose a radio button On or Off to submit input id="kot" ?

```
    <label><input type="radio" onClick="*???*" name="shfaq<?php echo $i; ?>" value="1" id="radiobuttonsondazh_0" <?php if($result['live']==1) echo 'checked'; ?> />Po</label>     
    <label><input type="radio" onClick="*???*" name="shfaq<?php echo $i; ?>" value="0" id="radiobuttonsondazh_1" <?php if($result['live']==0) echo 'checked'; ?> />Jo</label>

    <input id="kot" name="soralivetitull" type="submit" value="Shfaq" style="margin-top:1em" onclick="setWTF(this.form.soralivetitull);" />
```

Comment: Any attempt on your side?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
    document.forms["myform"].submit();
}
</script>

//give your form the id "myform"
<form id="myform" action="submit-form.php">
//and then call the function onCLick
<input type="radio" onClick="javascript: submitform()" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you can make a form out of this and do something explained here:

[W3Schools on form submitting](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp)
or you can make a submit function via ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'MyURLtoReceivePost',
            type: 'POST',
            cache : false,
            data : data,
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("error");
            }
        });
```

In which you could just include your own data {parameter_name : value, parameter_name2 : value2}
The information you can easily find in the jquery API

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

```
$( "#radiobuttonsondazh_0" ).click(function() {
  $( "#kot" ).submit();
});
```

Comment: you don't need jQuery for this, also this would only submit if the first radio button is clicked.

Comment: so what? the action for the second button is similar. anyway, it's better that nothing.

Comment: Conrad i dont know but i cant make it works :/ its do nothing when i chose a radiobuttonsondazh_0 :(

Comment: I hope You have created form that You want to submit first? If You want to stay at that page and dynamically send information to some point use AJAX with js/jquery.

Comment: @Conrad in your demo you are binding to `kot` which is a button not a form, you'd need to call `.click` or add a form to your answer and bind to the `id` or `selector` of that form.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Qmg9CpqT This is all my php file, and all i want to do if when i click on radio button to submit the form so its change it on the database to.

Comment: @abc123 You're right, it needs to be called to the form element not the sumbit button, I made mistake there. 

SiL3nt, if You want to do this like I said, just replace "#kot" with id of the form You want to submit

Comment: @Conrad the id of the form is #ole but it dint send information in database i have this to isset($_POST['soralivetitull']) what to put there ? The id of the form to or ?