# How to hide an iframe if content is empty?

Tags: html, iframe

I am using iframe in which I am displaying some content from external url. I want to hide the iframe if there is no content to display (i.e empty). Please let me know how to do this.
Thank you

```
<iframe id="iframe" width="100%" height="48" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="breaking.php" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

On the iframe content is:

```
<body>
<div class="centerbreaking">
<section id="breaking-news">
    <div id="breaking-news-main" class="shadow">
        <div id="breaking-news-title">Lajmi i fundit</div>
        <div id="breaking-news-inside">
          <ul id="breaking-news-list">

                     <li><label type="text" name="text0">celibashi: Ne Nuk e shohim presidentin Bujar Nishani si opozitë </label></li>
                      <li><label type="text" name="text1">Ilirjan Celibashi: Kemi respektuar institucionin e Presidentit</label></li>
                      <li><label type="text" name="text2">Ilirjan Celibashi: Qeveria nuk dha gjykim dhe koment për emërimet</label></li>
                      <li><label type="text" name="text3">Celibashi: Emërimet në Gjykatën e Lartë nga Kuvendi e Presidenti</label></li>
                      <li><label type="text" name="text4">Celibashi: Kam shumë besim që do të ecim në procesin e reformës </label></li>
                      <li><label type="text" name="text5">Ilirjan Celibashi: Komisioni do të vendos mbi çështjen e reformës</label></li>
                      <li><label type="text" name="text6">Celibashi: Presim që opozita të bashkëpunojë për këtë reformë </label></li>
                      <li><label type="text" name="text7">Celibashi: Reforma administrativo-territoriale e domosdoshme </label></li>
                      <li><label type="text" name="text8">Ilirjan Celibashi:Maxhoranca ka vullnet për të punuar me opozitën</label></li>
                                   </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
$(function() {
  $('#breaking-news-inside').vTicker();
});
</script>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to hide an iframe if content is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351594/how-to-hide-an-iframe-if-content-is-empty)

Comment: I saw that but its not working :/

Comment: How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215952/how-to-check-if-iframe-is-empty-null-undefined?lq=1)?

Comment: Is the same answer :( they explain just how to check lenght but i want how to hide it becouse iam new in how to make functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(function() {
        $('#iframe').load(function() {            
          if($.trim($(this).contents().find("body").html()) == "") {
            $(this).hide();
          }
        });
    });
   </script>
   <iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
```

---

*Works only if the iframe has the same domain as your page.*

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
if (!$("#iframe").contents().find("body").length) {
    $("#iframe").hide();
}</script>

<iframe id="iframe" width="100%" height="48" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="breaking.php" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

The iframe still there and it is in same domain

Comment: the this function is inside the iframe not on the page i put the iframe code. <iframe id="iframe" width="100%" height="48" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="breaking.php" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

Comment: Sorry kei its not hidding. Do u have time to come on my teamviewer ?

Comment: Sure, I got some time.

Comment: Id: 807374644 Pass 6860

Comment: Err nevermind. Didn't realize this requires a download. Don't have rights to download programs on this machine. Are you getting any errors in console by the way?

Comment: No iam not getting any error on the console. I put the code u gave to me on index.php with my iframe id=iframe and on the iframe scr i have dont have any thing right now just head section and <body></body>. The links are www.oranews.tv/index.php and www.oranews.tv/breaking.php is the page i iframe on index.php

Comment: Updated once again. Linking the website helped.

Comment: One problem, now its work to hide but when i have content like now its not showing :/ can u check the links again ? Look i have content now on breaking.php

Comment: You are the best... :) Work it. Can u take a look to this to? [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531428/radio-button-on-click-submit-input